# I want to access discount prize but its not getting

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code I want to calculate discount present.

There is one offer selection list if we select offer as yes then I shows `<div id="dis11">` i.e. `($("#dis11").show();)`. There is jquery call. In that `div` four text boxes are there `offerstart` date, end date, discount prize, discount%. I want to take discount prize in jquery call, but I didn't get it.

```
adis=document.getElementById("discount").value;
```

that's the problem.

In this there is prize text box which contains original prize of product. Using that prize and discount prize I have to calculate discount persent. On prize text box I gave `onblur` event. Bez if prize change discount present also going to change.

```
    <div class="formrow1">
        <div class="txttitle_large1">Prize</div>
        <div class="txtinputouter1">
           <input type="text" name="prize" id="prize1" onblur="prizf();">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="txttitle" style="width:30px;">Offer</div>
<div class="txtinputouter1">

    <select class="required" name="offer" id="offers" onChange="discountajax();"> 

         <option value="11">--Select offer--</option>
         <option value="1">yes</option>
         <option value="0">no</option>
    </select>
    <div id="discountinfo">
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width:70%;height:auto;float:left;margin-top:10px; display:none;" id="dis11">

    <div class="formrow1">
        <div class="txttitle_large1">OfferStart</div>
        <div class="txtinputouter1">
           <input type="text" name="offerstart" id="offerstart"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="formrow1">
        <div class="txttitle_large1">OfferEnd</div>
        <div class="txtinputouter1">
           <input type="text" name="offerEnd" id="offerEnd"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="formrow1">
        <div class="txttitle_large1">Discount Prize</div>
        <div class="txtinputouter1">
           <input type="text" name="discountprize" id="discount"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="formrow1">
        <div class="txttitle_large1">Discount%</div>
        <div class="txtinputouter1">
           <input type="text" name="discountpercent" id="discountpercent"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        --------script---------------

<script>
    function prizf()
    {
        alert("hi");

        discountajax();

    }
</script>
<script>

    function discountajax()
    {

        p=document.getElementById("prize1").value;
        alert(p);
        id1=document.getElementById("offers").value;
        alert(id1);
        if(id1==1)
        {

            $("#dis11").show();

            adis=document.getElementById("discount").value;
            alert(adis);

        }

    }

</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, please change the tags to javascript/jquery tags.

Comment: had you include jquery.js?

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

1. Your function `prizf` run only two times. one starting and second `onchange` but you are able to get the value of `discount` when it start to visible for entering values.
2. you are getting undefined `$` error because `jquery` is not included.

I create a function for getting value of `discount`.

check the below code.

*BTW this is not the standard code.*

```
<script>
    function discountajax()
    {
        p = document.getElementById("prize1").value;
        //alert(p);
        id1 = document.getElementById("offers").value;
        if (id1 == 1)
        {
            // alert("id"+id1);
            $("#dis11").show();
            adis = document.getElementById("discount").value;
            alert(adis);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#discount").focusout(function () {
            prizf();
        })
    })

</script>
```